# Does native C have common symbol?

Tags: c, gcc, symbols, gcc10

In GCC10, gcc default to `fno-common`. That means, all tentative defined symbols are not common. I think gcc conforms to the C specification but it seems there are no common symbols in the native C program. Are common symbols only for extension syntax?

Comment: "Common" symbols seems to be common (pun not intended) in older languages, mostly Fortran. GCC is an abbreviation of GNU Compiler Collection, it's a collection of compilers for many different languages. As Fortran is being one of the supported languages, GCC still have to support common symbols.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not relevant. `-fno-common` / `-fcommon` is a C-specific flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does native C have common symbol?

Read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf). **Its index don't even mention common symbols.**

Read carefully also the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

Perhaps you refer to the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file format used on Linux for [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). There you can find a mention of common symbols, which tend to be deprecated .... Read the Linux ABI specification, etc [here](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/).

My recommendation is to declare all your public symbols as `extern`  in some header file (`#include`-d in most of your `*.c` files), and define them *once* (without `extern`) in a *single* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). You could use simple [preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) tricks (such as [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)).

You might be interested in using C code generators such as [lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/), or develop your script (with [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) or [Python](https://python.org) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) etc... ....) for simple [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques ([autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) could be inspirational) generating some C code. Configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool ([GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)...) suitably.

You might be interested in using [static analyzer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) and [precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) of recent GCC. Look also into [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and [clang tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) and [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

You surely want to pass `-Wall -Wextra -g -H` [to](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) `gcc` and read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/download.html).

Answer (score 4):

No, it has nothing to do with "extension syntax", and it has nothing to do with "common symbols" as a language construct. It simply refers to the behavior of variable declarations at file scope.

C says that if you place a declaration like `int i;` in a file, and don't elaborate on it anywhere else, then it will have external linkage and it will be considered to be defined to have a value of 0. This is called a "tentative definition". Declarations with the same name in different files, if they have external linkage, all refer to the same variable. Generally the way to use external linkage is to define a variable in one file, and use an `extern` declaration in any other files that make use of it.

In GCC with `-fcommon`, tentative definitions for the same variable can appear in more than one file. GCC will resolve this at link time, and allocate storage (initialized to zero) for the variable once.

In GCC with `-fno-common`, tentative definitions are resolved to definitions ASAP when the file is compiled. If more than one file contains a tentative definition for a variable, then this will cause a multiple definition error at link time.

As far as I can tell, the C standard doesn't require or prohibit *either* behavior. In particular, C does not have C++'s "one definition rule". However, the `-fno-common` behavior is generally less surprising, catches a forgotten `extern` sooner, and allows the compiler to optimize better (because it knows exactly where the variable lives when compiling, instead of waiting to find out later). For these reasons the default was changed in GCC.

Comment: Re “As far as I can tell, the C standard doesn't require or prohibit either behavior”: This is covered by C 2018 6.9 5, “… If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression…, somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.” As it appears outside a constraint section, violating it does not require a diagnostic but makes the behavior “undefined” by the C standard, which licenses a C implementation to support either the common or no-common behavior.